# How to aggregate duplicate rows in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  Cell1    Cell2    Cell3     
    A          B       B      
    A          B       B       
    B          B       A     
    C          B       A
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
  Cell1    Cell2    Cell3     sum
    A          B       B       2 
    B          B       A       1
    C          B       A       1
```

I tried the aggregate function, but can't find the solution for this.

Comment: Use `df = df.groupby(['Cell1', 'Cell2', 'Cell3' ]).size().reset_index(name='sum')`

Comment: Check second answer in dupe.

Comment: Added another dupe link.